# Issues with hard disk secure erase

Tags: linux, hard-drive, secure-erase

I want to completely wipe all the data and both OSes (Ubuntu and Windows 7) from my hard drive. I tried DBAN but it gives me an error and does not run. I am looking for an alternative. After reading some articles online, I came to know that, using a Linux live CD, it can be done using either of following commands.

a) `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda`

b) `sudo shred -vfz -n 1 /dev/sda`

My questions are

1) Which option (a or b) is more secure (wipes everything) and faster?

2) Does either of the options damage the hard drive or anything? I want the hard drive to be usable again for Windows and Ubuntu etc.

**Edit**

I have one more interesting and related question.

3) Options a) and b) write zeros to every bit. Do they do that if the bit is already zero or do they leave it since it is zero.

Comment: What error did DBAN give?

Comment: Why are you worried, if you're going to keep the drive and just reuse it?

Comment: @Indrek "DBAN finished with non-fatal errors.
*ERROR /dev/sdb (process crash)
*ERROR /dev/sda (process crash)"

Comment: @DanielRHicks All I meant is the hard drive should remain usable for all OS types and purposes.

Comment: I was just wondering how paranoid you are.  Very simple schemes are more than adequate for anything not involving black helicopters.

Comment: kindly mention your solutions, i am new to these things :)

Comment: Simply erasing all "private" files and then writing files to the drive until it fills up will suffice.  One could probably devise a script.

Comment: I believe that will be done using a live cd. That should take 10 times more duration on an average than writing zeroes to the disk even using live cd.

Comment: what u r saying is good when one wants to erase empty space only, i guess not for complete disk erase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) faster, probably the dd if=/dev/zero command. It just dumps blocks of zeroes to the disk. I can't think of anything faster, since it's a simple block copy and dump.

2) more secure, shred. it writes multiple times. You may debate whether this is overkill or not.

Neither will cause any physical damage to the disk. They're both flinging bits, which is what the drive is supposed to do. The possible exception is SSDs, solid state disks, which have a limited number of writes, which you would use up somewhat with shred.

After either of these, you'd have an empty disk to format, then reinstall whatever OS/data you'd like.

Comment: The `shred` command you gave, John Watson, will write twice.  Once for the `-n 1` and once for the `-z`.  If you want to write more times for a more secure wipe, increment the `-n 1`.

Comment: i have 2 questions based on your reply. 1) why shred will run multiple times if i set passes to 1 via option -n ?  2) how to format the disk after wipe and how long will that take (i have 320 gb hdd) ?

Comment: @Kasius answered first question of previous comment. How to run shred for only one pass of zeroes ?

Comment: @JohnWatson 1) like Kasius said, there's -n1 for one random wipe, and the -z for a zero wipe, two wipes. 2a) the format depends on what OS you're using, and what makes sense if you need cross platform filesystem, this should be another question 2b) the time, depends. I can't tell you.

Comment: You can try leaving `-n 1` out, but it probably won't let you.  I'd stick with using `dd` if you just want to write zeroes.

Comment: You can try -n0 as well, but like @kasius says, why bother with this if all you want to do is a single wipe of zeros. dd works just as well in this regard.

Comment: So, how to format a wiped hard disk ?

Comment: In terms of actual security, `dd if=/dev/urandom ...` might be better, since writing zeroes can leave traces of magnetic bias. Depends how paranoid you are...

And to format it, just get a (Linux) boot disk, use `fdisk` to make the partitions (be sure to set their types properly!) and then run `mkfs.TYPE /dev/sdXX` (where TYPE is the format you want them in and /dev/sdXX is the partition).

Comment: @Actorclavilis thanks. there is something called "dell utility" partition on hard drive. i think that will be erased by dd as well. is that something important. will i be able to install windows after erasing that ? also, formatting can be done from windows install cd right ?

Comment: Two erases to each block in an SSD is pretty trivial.

Comment: The "dell utility" partition has got some pre-loaded Dell software; if you want to keep it, then just find out which partition (`/dev/sdXN`) it's on (using `fdisk` or `df -H`) and don't `dd` it. The `dd` call only overwrites the partition/disk you specify (so if your HDD is `/dev/sda` then you can do `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda` to erase the *entire* thing (multiple times to be extra certain) (this will also destroy the partition table) or if you have the Dell Utility on `/dev/sda1` and keep all your data on the partition `/dev/sda2`, then just use `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda2`)

Comment: New comment because of limits:

Yes, you can use the Windows install cd to recreate and format partitions, too, if you don't want to fool about with `fdisk` and `mkfs.*`.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of the methods you mention is actually "secure erase". SECURE ERASE is a defined part of the ATA specification, a method for instructing the drive firmware to erase the drive.

If you are in the U.S. government, it's also the currently approved method for securely erasing a modern hard drive (NIST 800-88). The old DoD "standard" that people like to refer to [doesn't actually specify any methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Industrial_Security_Program); they are specified [elsewhere](http://www.oregon.gov/DAS/OP/docs/policy/state/107-009-005_Exhibit_B.pdf) (and they are only degaussing and physical destruction, both of which make the drive unusable). Oops!

Unlike hack solutions such as `dd` and `shred`, the drive firmware is able to erase things that you can't, such as reallocated sectors. On self-encrypting drives, it merely destroys the encryption key and replaces it with a new key, making all the data unrecoverable (and only taking a second).

This is also the best method for erasing a SSD since it restores all cells to [factory write performance](http://www.anandtech.com/storage/showdoc.aspx?i=3531&p=8).

You can secure erase your drive [using the Linux `hdparm` command](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase), or by using the DOS utility [HDDErase.exe](http://cmrr.ucsd.edu/people/Hughes/SecureErase.shtml).

See also: [How can I reliably erase all information on a hard drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/5749/11291) and my article *ATA Security Exposed* in the Spring 2009 issue of *2600 Magazine*.